# Problem with immediate function definition

Tags: function-construction

I have a problem with the definition of a function that uses another function whose value is to be changed later.

For example:

```
g[x_] := 4
f[x_] = If[x < 3, g[x], 0]
```

If I then change the value of `g` , then `f` also varies; on the other hand, if I don't use the `If` function and define, for example:

```
f[x_] = g[x]
```

then `f` remains fixed, as I wanted.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` which is used to move code from a desktop to the cloud, so should be robust (in this example, it is also possible to use `DownValues` in a similar fashion). Basically, get the extended definition of your function `g` at the time of interest, and then use that function in the definition of the function `f`. Here is an example of a function `g`:

```
g[1] = "one";
g[n_Integer] = "integer";
g[n_Real] = "real";
g[n_Rational] = "rational";
```

Using `` Language`ExtendedDefinition `` to burn this definition of `g` into the definition of `f`:

```
With[{def = Language`ExtendedDefinition["g"]},
    f[x_] := Block[{g},
        Language`ExtendedDefinition["g"] = def;
        If[x<3, g[x], 0]
    ]
]
```

Now, clear `g`:

```
Clear[g]
```

Check whether `f` still behaves as expected:

```
f[1]
f[2]
f[3/2]
f[1.5]
f[10]
```

> "one"
>
> "integer"
>
> "rational"
>
> "real"
>
> 0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the value for `f` remains unevaluated until the `If`'s condition can be verified as `True` or `False`. As such, `g[x]` is re-evaluated every time the condition can be checked.

To avoid this, use memoization:

```
f[x_] := f[x] = If[x < 3, g[x], 0];
```

This makes `f` save its value at each `x` every time it is evaluated.

Alternatively, if even memoization allows too many different function evaluations and you need to use the same `g` in every use of `f`, then embed `g[x]` in the definition by doing something like:

```
f[x_] := If[x < 3, Evaluate[g[x]], 0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With[{g = Function[x, 4]},
 f = Function[x, If[x < 3, g[x], 0]]
 ]
```